# Big image don't show in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

Trying to load a big image fails in react-native. Using a smaller image works as intended but a big one just doesn't show and no error is thrown.

There is a limitation on how big a image can be in React-native? Or in Android?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

export default class RobberJob extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./assets/map.png')} style={{width:200, height:200}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RobberJob', () => RobberJob);
```

Comment: what it show any error or Blank ?

Answer (score 0):

If your image is really huge, wait a moment until it's loaded. Or is your image is just white?! ;-)

Here's your code with a big (5360 × 3560) image and it's working: https://repl.it/Iqe9